# Javascript for/of loop (with a filereader) breaks on 2nd iteration, but works perfectly as a snippet in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, filereader, code-snippets, for-of-loop

Be nice. I'm a noob and this is my first SO question...

Here is some JS code from my script:

```
let outputArr = [];

let flNum = 0;
let unrecognizedFiles = 0;

async function readFiles() {
    const inputFiles = Array.from(pluFolderInput.files);
    for (const file of inputFiles) {
        flNum++
        const fileData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = () => {console.log(`completed ${file.name}.`)
                resolve(fr.result)
            };
            fr.onloadstart = () => { console.log(`started ${file.name}.`) };
            fr.onerror = () => {
                reject("Failed to read file! " + fr.error);
            };
            fr.readAsText(file);
        });
        if (!fileData.startsWith("ISA*")) {
            unrecognizedFiles++;
            return;
        };
    };
};

readFiles();
```

When I run it in the larger script I do not get the desired output. Instead, the script breaks and the page just reloads.
The debugger (Chrome dev tools) shows me that the first iteration of the loop performs exactly how I want it to. But as soon as `fr.readAsText(file);` is executed on the **second** file everything breaks.

What's more exciting is that I copied the exact lines of code into a brand new Snippet, and when I run it there, independent of the rest of the script, it works perfectly!

Any clues as to

1. Why a loop might break on the second iteration if the first works fine?
2. Why this code might work in the Snippet, but not in my script?
3. What I can do to hunt down the problem?

Thanks in advance!

**As requested in the comments, here is more of the code from the script to show how the data is handled in each iteration:**

```
pluCrunchBtn.addEventListener('click', addPymtFilesToLog);

async function addPymtFilesToLog() {
    document.querySelector("#plu-loader").classList.add("is-active");
    const flCount = pluFolderInput.files.length;
    let svcsAdded = 0;
    let svcsUpdated = 0;
    let svcsUnchanged = 0;
    let flNum = 0;
    let clmCount = 0;
    let unrecognizedFiles = 0;
    const inputFiles = Array.from(pluFolderInput.files);
    for (const file of inputFiles) {
        flNum++
        const fileData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = () => {
                console.log("reading started.")
                resolve(fr.result)
            };
            fr.onloadstart = () => { console.log("reading started.") };
            fr.onerror = () => {
                reject("Failed to read file!\n\n" + fr.error);
            };
            fr.readAsText(file);
        });
        if (!fileData.startsWith("ISA*")) {
            unrecognizedFiles++;
            return;
        }
        const splitFile = fileData.split("~");
        const payer = splitFile.find(el => el.includes("N1*PR")).split("\*")[2];
        const clinic = splitFile.find(el => el.includes("N1*PE")).split("\*")[2];
        const fileDateString = splitFile.find(el => el.includes("BPR")).split("\*")[16];
        const fileDate = fileDateString.slice(0, 4) + "-" + fileDateString.slice(4, 6) + "-" + fileDateString.slice(6);
        const fileClaims = (fileData.split("CLP")).slice(1);
        clmCount += fileClaims.length;
        fileClaims.forEach(cl => {
            let svcs = cl.split("SVC");
            const claimInfo = svcs[0].split("~");
            const claimPymtInfo = claimInfo[0].split("\*");
            const claimNum = claimPymtInfo[1];
            const claimAmtClmd = claimPymtInfo[3];
            const claimAmtPaid = claimPymtInfo[4];
            const claimPatInfo = claimInfo.find(el => el.includes("NM1*QC")).split("\*");
            const claimPatLN = claimPatInfo[3];
            const claimPatFN = claimPatInfo[4];
            const claimPatIdCodeQlfr = claimPatInfo[8];
            const claimPatIdCode = claimPatInfo[9];
            svcs = svcs.slice(1);
            svcs.forEach(svc => {
                const svcPymtInfo = svc.split("~").find(el => el.includes("*HC:")).split("\*")
                const svcProcCode = svcPymtInfo[1].split("\:")[1];
                const svcSubmtdAmt = svcPymtInfo[2];
                const svcAmtPaid = svcPymtInfo[3];
                const svcDateRaw = svc.split("~").find(el => el.includes("DTM*472")).split("\*")[2];
                const svcDate = svcDateRaw.slice(0, 4) + "-" + svcDateRaw.slice(4, 6) + "-" + svcDateRaw.slice(6);
                const svcCtrlNum = svc.split("~").find(el => /REF\*6R\*/.test(el)).split("\*")[2]; //
                const svcAdjsmtLine = svc.split("~").find(el => el.includes("CAS*")).split("\*");
                const svcAdjmntGroupCode = svcAdjsmtLine[1];
                const svcAdjmntReasonCode = svcAdjsmtLine[2];
                const svcAdjmntAmt = svcAdjsmtLine[3];

                let svcItem = {
                    'SvcDate': svcDate,
                    'PatLN': claimPatLN,
                    'PatFN': claimPatFN,
                    'SvcProcCode': svcProcCode,
                    'AmtSbmtd': svcSubmtdAmt,
                    'AmtPaid': svcAmtPaid,
                    'AmtAdjstd': svcAdjmntAmt,
                    'AdjsmtGrpCode': svcAdjmntGroupCode,
                    'AdjsmtRsnCode': svcAdjmntReasonCode,
                    'Payer': payer,
                    'ClaimNum': claimNum,
                    'ClaimAmt': claimAmtClmd,
                    'ClaimAmtPaid': claimAmtPaid,
                    'PatIDQlfr': claimPatIdCodeQlfr,
                    'PatID': claimPatIdCode,
                    'SvcCtrlNum': svcCtrlNum,
                    'Clinic': clinic,
                    'FileDate': fileDate,
                    'FileName': file.name,
                    'Note': ""
                }

                if (!newLogFile) {
                    const matchedSvcLineIndex = csvData.findIndex(itm => {
                        return itm.ClaimNum === claimNum && itm.SvcCtrlNum === svcCtrlNum;
                    });
                    if (matchedSvcLineIndex !== -1 && csvData[matchedSvcLineIndex].FileDate < fileDate) {
                        const oldFileName = csvData[matchedSvcLineIndex].FileDate
                        svcItem.Note = "Updated. Last file: " + oldFileName;
                        csvData[matchedSvcLineIndex] = svcItem;
                        svcsUpdated++;
                    }
                    else if (matchedSvcLineIndex !== -1) {
                        // Else if exists--but not newer...
                        svcsUnchanged++;
                    }
                    else {
                        csvData.push(svcItem);
                        svcsAdded++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    csvData.push(svcItem);
                    svcsAdded++;
                }

                if (Array.from(pluFolderInput.files).indexOf(file) + 1 === flCount && fileClaims.indexOf(cl) + 1 === fileClaims.length && svcs.indexOf(svc) + 1 === svcs.length) {
                    csvData.sort((a, b) => (a.SvcDate > b.SvcDate) ? 1 : ((b.SvcDate > a.SvcDate) ? -1 : 0));
                    const date = new Date();
                    const dtStamp = new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substring(0, 16).replace("T", "_").replace(":", "");
                    document.querySelector("#plu-loader").classList.remove("is-active");
                    if (confirm("Files processed: " + flCount +
                        "\nClaims processed: " + clmCount +
                        "\nServices Added: " + svcsAdded +
                        "\nServices Updated: " + svcsUpdated +
                        "\nServices Unchanged: " + svcsUnchanged +
                        "\n\nClick 'Ok' to download the new log file.")) {
                        generateDownload("PaymentLog_" + dtStamp + ".csv", Papa.unparse(csvData));
                    };
                }
            })
        })
    };
    if (unrecognizedFiles > 0) {
        confirm("NOTE:  " + unrecognizedFiles + " (of " + flCount + ") files in the selected folder were not recognized as valid payment files.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The page reloads? This means it crashed, probably because of a lack of memory. How big are the files you are trying to read? What are you doing with the result after?

Comment: The files are simple text. Most are very small, max file size is a few hundred KB. After they are read the script extracts bits of data and organizes them into objects. Each object is added to an array, which becomes an output file.
I was thinking memory too, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Without seeing the full code it's hard to say. Could you try to set up an [MCVE] please? You can create live snippet from the question by clicking the [<>] icon.

Comment: added code to the question

Comment: ... This is unfortunately not really a [MCVE]. We need it to be *minimal*, in that you remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce the bug. So you start by removing some logic and see if it still reproduces, if it doesn't, remove something else. When removing any logic makes the bug disappear, it is "minimal". Then we need it to be "reproducible". Meaning without having to guess anything we should be able to execute the code and see the bug too. Here we lack a lot: html, some functions like `generateDownload` etc.

Comment: And if doing so you find the cause by yourself, don't hesitate to still [edit] your question with the real minimal repro and to post a self-answer, this might help someone else.